# Prim MST algorithm optimization

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, minimum-spanning-tree

I am implementing Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning tree.
the algorithm works correctly.
but it would take too much time if i have a graph with 10000 nodes.
here is the example of how i store the graph in my code:

```
graph = {0: {1: 6, 5: 3}, 
1: {0: 6 , 6: 3 , 2: 9}, 
2: {1: 9, 7: 3 , 3: 5}}
```

Here is how i get my adolescences:

```
def adjacent(graph, u): # adjacencies of vertex u
    return graph[u].keys()
```

Here is how i calculate the weight of the edge between two nodes:

```
def w(u,v):
    L = cartesian_product[u].keys()
    if v in L:
        return cartesian_product[u].get(v)
    return 999999
```

And here is my algorithm to calculate the wieght of the minimum spanning tree with Prim's algorithm:

```
def prim(graph):
    total_mst_cost=0
    # put all nodes in a heap
    h=[(0,0)] 
    for i in range(1,n*k):
        heappush(h, (999999,i))
    while len(h)!=0 : #till there is a node left in the heap
        (key,u) = heappop(h)
        total_mst_cost += key
        # check hte adjacences of node-->
        adj = adjacent(graph,u)

        f = operator.itemgetter(1)
        ff = map(f, h)
        for v in adj:
            # update the labels:
            _ww = w(u,v)
            try: i = ff.index(v)
            except: continue
            if v==h[i][1] and _ww < h[i][0]:
                h[i]=(_ww, h[i][1])
        heapify(h)
            # for i in range(len(h)):
            #     if v==h[i][1] and _ww < h[i][0]:
            #         h[i]=(_ww, h[i][1])
            #         heapify(h)
    return total_mst_cost
```

Comment: Why do you store it as a *list* of dictionaries?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry just a mistake, i edited my post

Comment: The algorithm is named after Prim, not prime. (Also it is the name of the author so we capitalize it).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thank you, i edited the mistake

Answer (score 0):

### Idea 1

The initialization of the heap:

```
for i in range(1,n*k):
    heappush(h, (999999,i))
```

is unnecessary.  If all nodes are reachable you can simply delete these two lines.

### Idea 2

The weight extraction:

```
L = cartesian_product[u].keys()
```

seems slow.  I am not quite sure what type cartesian_product is, but if it is a dictionary then it should be faster to test for inclusion with `u in cartesian_product` than by extracting a list of keys and searching them.

### Idea 3

You call heapify after each iteration.  I believe this is because you wish to be able to adjust the weights in the heap queue.

An alternative faster approach to this is documented in the Python documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) and works by marking certain values as being removed using a dictionary.

### Idea 4

If this isn't for educational reasons, I would recommend using Networkx, a Python library with graph algorithms.  In this library you can replace all your code with a function call to [minimum_spanning_tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree)